# Include css and javascript in PyroCMS theme

Tags: pyrocms, pyro

How do i include a css and javascript from system/assets/css or js directory in my theme.

we include js or css file like

```
{pyro:theme:css file="style.css"}
{pyro:theme:js file="jquery.1.5.js"}
```

but i want to use a js file included in system/assets/js directory

Answer (score 3):

pyro:theme just access theme assets and partials.

Use asset pyro tags:

```
{pyro:asset:js file="front.js"}
{pyro:asset:js file="front.js" module="domains"}
```

Generates:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/system/pyrocms/assets/js/front.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/addons/modules/domains/js/front.js"></script>
```

+info: http://pyrocms.com.roy.getcloudigniter.com/docs/tag-reference/asset